# Number of non-identity elements of order $2$ in this set. (Related to abelian group of order $34.$)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

This question was asked in a bachelor exam for which I am preparing and I was unable to solve it.

> Let $G$ be an abelian group of order $34$ and $S=\{ g \in G \mid g=g^{-1}\}$ . Then what is the  number of non- identity elements in $S$?

I used sylow theorem: There is $1$ sylow subgroup of order $17$ and $17$ sylow subgroups of order $2$ but $17$ is not the answer ( I'm not even close!) .

What is wrong in my approach? Can you please tell?

Comment: perhaps there is only one element/subgroup of order $2$

Comment: Suppose that $G$ were cyclic of order $34$.  What is the answer in that case?

Comment: $G$ is Abelian, has an element of order $2$ and an element of order $17$, hence it has an element of order $34=\mathrm{lcm}(2,17)$.

Comment: Cf. [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2534270/groups-of-order-34/2534286#2534286)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a finite abelian group $G$, there's only one $p$ Sylow subgroup for all $p$. This follows from the Sylow theorems: all $p$ Sylow subgroups are conjugate, but in an abelian group, conjugation doesn't do anything. Thus an abelian group of order $34=2 \cdot 17$ will have one $2$-Sylow subgroup and hence one non-identity element $g \in G$ satisfying $g=g^{-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Since $\lvert G\rvert=34=17\times 2$, by the classification theorem for groups of order $2p$ for prime $p$ greater than two,${}^\dagger$ we have that either $G\cong \Bbb Z_{2p}$ or $G\cong D_p$, the dihedral group of order $2p$. (Let $p=17$.)

But $G$ is abelian, so . . .

---

$\dagger$: Theorem 7.3 of Gallian's *"Contemporary Abstract Algebra (Eighth Edition)"*.

Answer (score 0):

By the classification theorem for finite abelian groups, $G$ is cyclic of order 34. A finite cyclic group of order $n$ has exactly one subgroup of order $d$ for any $d\mid n$, so there is exactly one subgroup of order two. Since any element of order two generates a subgroup of order two, there is precisely one such element. So there are two elements with $g=g^{-1}$: the identity and the unique element of order two.